# VB.Net - HttpWebRequest - What Url encoding to use to get specific characters for POST message

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

The server on which I'm trying to send POST is probably written in PHP, and I'm using VB.Net - HttpWebRequest as client.

Trying to encode message to send post but it doesn't work.

I decided to caught the exact encoding characters which the server uses through Fiddler application, by trying to send data via a regular browser, and I realize that it's slightly different with .Net **WebUtility.UrlEncode** & **EscapeUriString** & "Uri.EscapeDataString" characters.

I also used "HtmlEncode" and other .net encoding methods without success.

Now, I'd like to know what **url encoding** to use in order to get below characters.

***1. Message to Send POST***

```html
MR CHEAP TRANSPORT - 50 YEARS EXCELLENCE
WE ARE SERIOUS ON SERVICE AND AFFORDABILITY
HOME AND OFFICE MOVES
```

***2. POST Characters from Regular Browser***

```html
%3Cp%3EMR+CHEAP+TRANSPORT+-+20+YEARS+EXCELLENCE%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3EWE+ARE+SERIOUS+ABOUT+SERVICE+AND+AFFORDABILITY%26nbsp%3B%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3EHOME+AND+OFFICE+MOVES%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E
```

***3. POST Characters from Regular Browser***

```html
MR+CHEAP+TRANSPORT+-+30+YEARS+EXCELLENCE%0AWE+ARE+SERIOUS+ABOUT+SERVICE+AND+AFFORDABILITY+%0A%0AHOME+AND+OFFICE+MOVES%0A
```

Comment: the strange thing is I can post the same data to any other category of that web site, but only to one specific category that doesn't post. and I can only post to that specific category if I use normal characters and few words only like 2 / 3 lines.

Comment: cool, I have never heard about that. let me try it and will get back to you.

Comment: Well, i'd say URLencode, but you must include an header in your POST request saying it's urlencoded, else the server wont budge. `<httpwebrequest>.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`